# Python Virtualenv Check Environment

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am writing a bash script which need to start a service using `virtualenv`. I imagine my bash script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/user/python-ev/bin/activate
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port 8889 --profile pyspark" pyspark --master spark://701.datafireball.com:7077
```

However, I want to add a line between `activate` and `IPYTHON...` to make sure that the environment has been activated. Is there an environment variable / command in the shell that can tell me if I am inside a virtualenv or not, if so, which one?

I can hard-code to print the Python path, where it should point to a customized Python interpreter if I am inside the virtualenv, but I am not sure if that is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check for the environment variable **VIRTUAL_ENV** and see if it has the correct source path. Now if it doesn't exist then you know it's not activated. If it does, you need to check and see if it has the correct path.

The correct bash snippet that will work to check if the variable is set or not is the following

```
if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
    echo "No VIRTUAL_ENV set"
else
    echo "VIRTUAL_ENV is set"
fi
```

Comment: Session is inside VENV or not, ``$VIRTUAL_ENV`` seems to be always empty if ``echo``ed from within a bash script.